# Using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to create a CSV file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm trying to create a file that will specifically be a .csv filetype using the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent. Here is the code I currently have:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, ".csv");
startActivityForResult(intent, myRequestCode);
```

And here is the code for my onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent dataIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, dataIntent);

    // TODO: make the requestCode a global variable
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && dataIntent != null ) {
        if (requestCode == 0) { // user clicked "Database CSV"
            try {
                if(! dataIntent.getData().getPath().endsWith(".csv")) {
                    
                }

                OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(dataIntent.getData());
                myDb.export_toDatabaseCSV_withOutputStream(outputStream);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully exported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // TODO: make this an actual check based on the result of myDb.export
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File could not be created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Uri path returned from dataIntent.getData().getPath() = "/document/primary:Download/myFileName". I can't seem to find a way to edit the File's name inside of the the if statement.

EXTRA_TITLE has similar functionality to what I want, but isn't quite what I need. I want users to be able to specify the filename in the activity without having to add .csv to the end of the file name. For example, if a user creates a file named "MyData", when the activity ends I want the file to be renamed "MyData.csv".

Comment: Try `text/csv` as the MIME type and get rid of `EXTRA_TITLE`. However, in general, this isn't your decision -- how that activity handles extensions is up to the developers of that activity (Google and possibly device manufacturers), not you or I.

Comment: You can check the filename in onActivityResult. If it does not end with the wanted extension you can directly rename the file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried this but it doesn't seem to actually do anything. At the very least, it doesn't add the desired filetype.

Comment: @blackapps I've had a lot of issues grabbing the file due to my lack of understanding of the Android file type/URI type system. What would be an example code snippet that would check file type and change the name if needed?

Comment: Show your onActivityResult and tell the values of data.getData().toString().

Comment: @blackapps it's actually an open Git repo here: https://github.com/PhenoApps/Prospector/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/phenoapps/prospector/Selection_Scan.java. I'll edit my post to include the onActivityResult snippet

Comment: `dataIntent.getData().getPath()` Look at `dataIntent.getData().toString()` instead. I said that before.

Comment: Create a DocumentFile instance for the obtained uri to rename.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it should work

```
   intent.setType("text/comma-separated-values")
```

If possible kindly share with us this function that you have used  `myDb.export_toDatabaseCSV_withOutputStream(outputStream);`